# iOS: Edit a file in an external App

Tags: ios, file-sharing, external-application

Here is a simple question (the answer might not be as simple, I guess...)

In my App, I have a .XLSX file that I want to open with Apple's Number App for edition (or any other App that can edit such files), and take the edited file back into my App

I know it's possible to open a file with an external App, but how can I take it back once edited ?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Create a temporary copy of the file, pass it to the external app and then monitor the file for changes.

Comment: But, won't the file be copied into the target App's "Document" directory ? In that case, the file I monitor will never be updated